# How to create multiple instances of the same type as Spring beans based on configuration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, autowired

I am trying to figure out how to create several instance beans of subclasses of a class based on application.properties configurations.

As an example, essentially I have multiple backend services for payment processing, with the respective integrations built as sub-classes of a parent integration type, say: PaymentProcessorAlpha and ProcessorBeta both of which extend the PaymentProcessor class.

Now, what seems to be the tricky part, is I want to be able configure different Processor instantiated objects (ideally Spring Beans, but if they are just objects that’s okay) for a list of given currencies, as configured in the application.properties file.

So based on the configuration in application.properties:

```
CurrencyProcessorStuff.processors.USD=alpha
CurrencyProcessorStuff.processors.CAD=alpha
CurrencyProcessorStuff.processors.GBP=beta
CurrencyProcessorStuff.processors.MXN=beta
CurrencyProcessorStuff.processors.AUS=beta
```

(I can use the above config to populate the “processors” Map property of the CurrencyProcessorStuff Bean with a Map of String, String, being the Currency Name and Processor Name, i.e. <“USD”->”Alpha”, “CAD”->”Alpha”, etc...)

I want to create five instances of PaymentProcessor, two of sub-type PaymentProcessorAlpha, and three of sub-type PaymentProcessorBeta, and be able to reference the correct instance based on the currency I am dealing with at the moment, either via different bean names, @Qualifier, or simply by having created a Map of those objects with the key of the currency name.

I believe that I can solve this two different ways, but neither feels very clean or Spring-like, so I am hoping there is a better way.

A) I can use full class names in the configuration, instead of “alpha” and I can manually create new objects of those class names and build myself a Map of CurrencyName->ProcessorObjects.

I don’t like this because I have to manually code in full class names, keep everything in sync, and I don’t get Spring Beans, just POJOs.

B) I can create factory classes for each processor type, Autowire them into a collection identified by Class name or Qualifier name, and then call the appropriate factory Bean to generate a POJO for my map (similar to option A but without coding full class names into the .properties file.

I see how you can use Qualifier to get the correct sub-type of a Bean for a given property via Autowiring, but I haven’t figure out how to get multiple instances of each sub-type and have a nice way to name/find each bean, etc... managed via .properties file configurations.

Any thoughts would be appreciated!